# JLink does not preserve the input cell number

Tags: java

I use JLink for connecting to the Mathematica kernel and evaluate some expressions. The In[] prompt is not continuous - it has step 3. I.e. the first expression is In[1] and after the evaluation the next one is In[4]. I obtained this kind of behavior on the rescent Mathematica 10.0.1 for Mac OS X 10.10. Is it a JLink bug?

Comment: You may be loading an init.m which would execute first?

Comment: Actually I would guess that it is probably not even documented what the `In` prompt should behave like when the Kernel is called via JLink. Can you explain why that is a problem? Assuming it is not recommended to rely on a specific ordering of `In` statements when programmatically using the Kernel it would seem irrelevant what these are for a JLink program, wouldn't it?

Comment: Say you use the MathSessionPane class from the JLink package and the user sees the In[] prompt while entering and evaluating the expressions. Any two sequential evaluations have In[] index gap. Nothing can prevent user from refering to the previous evaluation and this gap is misleading - it is not clear which if % can use the numbers visible as prompt the prompt.

Comment: OK I see, that is of course somewhat disturbing. I have not realized that one can see this not only as an example but also as a building block. It looks like the Kernel/Mathlink behaviour has changed from version 8 to 9 so that now the numbering is wrong, the numbering for the example works correct for older versions (which it presumably was written for). I have no idea how to solve that, you might want to report it to WRI. What is it that you are trying to build?

Comment: I am trying to build a simple front end for IntellyJ Idea ide without compile time dependency ont JLink.jar. See https://github.com/dubrousky/Mathematica-REPL

Answer (score 2):

I looked in the code of new JLink package of the Mathematica 10.0.1: it has 2 more evaluations under the hood per each evaluation and discards the answer from the Kernel. One is a preEval method that sets the evaluation format and another is postEval.

```
MathSessionTextPane.this.ml.evaluate("{JLink`Private`cfv, JLink`Private`sopts, JLink`Private`ddf} = {FormatValues[Continuation], Options[\"stdout\"], $DisplayFunction} ; Format[Continuation[_], OutputForm] = \"\" ; SetOptions[\"stdout\", FormatType -> OutputForm, CharacterEncoding -> \"Unicode\", PageWidth -> " + paneWidthInChars + "] ; " + "$DisplayFunction = " + df + ";");


MathSessionTextPane.this.ml.evaluate("FormatValues[Continuation] = JLink`Private`cfv ; SetOptions[\"stdout\", JLink`Private`sopts] ; $DisplayFunction = JLink`Private`ddf ;");
```